# python comprehension and set's. receiving error

Tags: python

I have this python code: `{n[word] for word in n if word in words}`

however I get the following error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`. this is because `n[word]` retuns a set. However, I am not sure How I would fix this code. I know a simple for loop could resolve it though.

example data:

```
n = {'corporal': {35}, 'moral': {34}, 'purpose': {33, 34, 14, 49}, 'simulations': {42}, 'consultant': {16, 40, 38}, 'Indies': {3}, 'murdered': {10}}
words = ['moral', 'Indies']
```

expected ouput:

```
{34, 3}
```

Comment: hey, can you explain what's your goal? build dictionary? list? an example of the result you want will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `frozenset` objects instead:

```
{frozenset(n[word]) for word in n if word in words}
```

Objects in a set need to be immutable to be hashable. `set()` objects are mutable, but `frozenset()` are not. They are to `set`s what `tuple`s are to `list`s.

If you were instead trying to create a *union* of all the sets, then just create a new, empty set and pass your generator expression to that:

```
set().union(*(n[word] for word in n if word in words))
```

This builds *one* set with the union of all your matched sets.

Demos against your test input:

```
>>> n = {'corporal': {35}, 'moral': {34}, 'purpose': {33, 34, 14, 49}, 'simulations': {42}, 'consultant': {16, 40, 38}, 'Indies': {3}, 'murdered': {10}}
>>> words = ['moral', 'Indies'] 
>>> {frozenset(n[word]) for word in n if word in words}
set([frozenset([34]), frozenset([3])])
>>> set().union(*(n[word] for word in n if word in words))
set([34, 3])
```

Because `n` is a dictionary, you can do this a little faster still by using [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
>>> set().union(*(n[k] for k in n.viewkeys() & words))
set([34, 3])
```

or if you are using Python 3, `.keys()` returns a view objects by default:

```
>>> set().union(*(n[k] for k in n.keys() & words))
set([34, 3])
```

Comment: @dgamma3: it passes the following expression as separate arguments to `.union()`. If `arguments` is a list of `[1, 2, 3]`, then `callable(*arguments)` calls `callable()` with 3 separate arguments, set to `1`, `2`, and `3`.